# File Upload multiple files in asp.net (similar to gmail)

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I need suggestions with regards to the multiple file upload using File Upload control in asp.net(along with C#).

I have a File Upload Control, so i click the 'Browse' button and when i select a file from the select file dialog, i want the file to be shown as a link below the File Upload Control( somewhat similar to gmail). This file should be seen such a way that it can be deleted, if i wanted to. And also i should be able to upload another file from the File Upload control.
All these files should be uploaded to a location when i use a button click event in the end.

I think i have made myself clear. 
Any Suggestions are really helpful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the user selects file, use client javascript to:

1. Hide the file upload control
2. Create a link in its place
3. Create a "delete" link next to it, which will a) remove the original upload control from the page and b) remove both links created in steps 2 and 3
4. Create a new file upload control and place it above the link created in step 2

If you have any questions left, I will try to answer.

Comment: that is clear, my question now is regarding how to implement the javascript to create a link for the file selected?

Comment: Please clarify. Are you unclear on how to create a link and insert into page? Or are you unclear on how to obtain the name of the file selected in the upload control?

Comment: i think its clear now !! Ill give a try tommorrow and get back. thanks Fyodor

Comment: If it helps you, would you the be so kind to accept my answer? (just click the big hollow "checkmark" next to it)